# unordered_map MSVC invalidation guarantee

Tags: c++, unordered-map

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-map-class?view=msvc-160 MS states:

> "inserting an element invalidates no iterators"

But the book "The C++ Standard Library" by Nicolai Josuttis and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map both state that `insert` may invalidate iterators if `insert` causes a rehash.

Is MS simply providing a stronger guarantee than the standard? If so, are implementations allowed to do such things?

thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each compiler vendor must at the minimum comply with the guarantees of the standard, however they are free to offer stronger guarantees if they so choose. For example, all compilers worth their salt guaranteed return value optimization (RVO) long before the standard mandated it.

Comment: Other stronger guarantees that many compilers offer are that a `char` is 8 bits, that signed values use twos compliment, that `int` is 4 bytes, etc.